# Building General Linear Mixed Model in R

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, glmm

I am trying to build a `glmm` in R but constantly get error messages (I am a complete beginner).

I have conducted an experiment with Camera traps in which I tested, if they react to a target, that I pulled in front of them, so my response variable is binomial.
I try to build a GLMM, in which all the variables are fixed factors and day (in which the experiment was conducted is a random factor). Could anyone more experienced tell me what I am doing wrong (I first try only with one explanatory variable)?

I tried it with the `glmm()` and with `lmer()`:

```r
library(glmm)
set.seed(1234)
ptm <- proc.time()
Detections <- glmm(Detection ~ 0 + Camera, random = list(~ 0 + Day), 
    varcomps.names = c("Day"), data = data1, family.glmm = bernoulli.glmm, 
    m = 10^4, debug = TRUE)`
```

This one produces an obscenely large glmm, even with the minimal dataset.

and with

```r
library(lme4)
Detections_glmm <- lmer(Detection ~ Camera + (1|Day), family="binomial")
```

This one gives the following error message:

```r
Error in lmer(Detection ~ Camera + (1 | Day), family = "binomial") : 
  unused argument (family = "binomial")
```

Here is a minimal df:

```r
data.frame(
    Detection = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
             Temperature = as.factor(c("10","10","10","10","10","20","20",
                                       "0","0","0")),
                Distance = as.factor(c("75","75","75","225","225","225",
                                       "75","150","150","150")),
                    Size = as.factor(c("0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1",
                                       "2","2")),
                   Light = as.factor(c("1","1","1","1","1","0","0","0",
                                       "0","0")),
                  Camera = as.factor(c("1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3",
                                       "1","1")),
                     Day = as.factor(c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3",
                                       "3","2"))
```

And Information about the variables:
Response variable:
Detection (binomial)

Explanatory variables:
Temperature of bottle: (0, 10, 20)
Distance from Camera (75, 150, 225)
Light(0/1)
Size of bottle (0, 1, 3)

Comment: I've never used `glmm`, but for `lme4` you need to use `glmer()` not `lmer()` to use a **generalized** lm with a link function.

Comment: I haven't done a "binomial" GLMM, but done many LMM's, and using Day as random factor will generally mean you need more than three levels. (I understand this may just be sample data, so this is just a heads up if you hadn't considered it.) https://peerj.com/articles/12794/

Comment: Wonderful! That is very helpful indeed!

Comment: The glmer() was the right way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Could someone (possibly the OP) please post an answer?

Comment: @BenBolker the model works correctly, if you change lmer to glmer as GregorThomas has suggested.

Comment: I know.  These are all **comments**.  I want someone to post an appropriate **answer** based on the comments ...

Answer (score 0):

Using `glmer` should work. (`lmer` is only for **linear** mixed models, i.e. Gaussian responses.)

```r
Detections_glmm <- glmer(Detection ~ Camera + (1|Day),    family="binomial")
```

If you really only have 3 days in your data set, you probably want to treat `Day` as a fixed rather than a random effect, see e.g. the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random) or [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/what-is-the-minimum-recommended-number-of-groups-for-a-random-effects-factor) ...